# How do I disable bluetooth startup (by default, with every boot) in 17.04?

Tags: bluetooth, startup, restart

I was just wondering how to disable bluetooth startup by default in 17.04. I would like to be able to boot, and not have to turn off bluetooth every time. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you can turn it off in the systemsettings and it will stay offline?

If this doesn't work you can disable the service itself.

`sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service && sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service`

If you want to activate it again.

`sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service && sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service`

The enable and disable is used so during the next startup it is either started or not.

Comment: Not really the answer.... I want to know how to get bluetooth to not come on at startup, but be readily AVAILABLE to use. I don't want to disable the bluetooth completely then have to re-enable it when I use bluetooth. I just don't want the unnecessary bluetooth service running while I'm not using it. I'll never remember, if I need bluetooth, that I need to run some cmd bs to get it working again.

Comment: Huh? You don't want to disable it so use just the stop/start command. I did write the enable/disable is for if you don't want it to be run during start up. Read it completly before answering in such vulgar language.

Comment: Did I need to reboot for this to take effect? I'll accept the answer if so. I didn't reboot or log out, so maybe it was my bad. I'm on Ubuntu GNOME now, and I don't have the same problem so I can't check.....

Comment: The stop/start is during runtime. So no usually you never have to reboot a linux computer to make changes have effect, except if you want to change the kernel maybe.

Comment: Okay well this answer never worked for me, sorry. Idk what it was about my system but in this specific case, that wasn't the answer for whatever reason.

Comment: The OP would like the Blueman to stay in the systray, but the system as a whole to boot up essentially with the right-click option "Turn Bluetooth Off" already done. The systemctl options disable Blueman altogether, making it more difficult to use Bluetooth.